# react native stop useEffect() infinite loop

Tags: react-native

I made a page that requests an API every 5 seconds, when there's new data it navigates to another screen,
but it does not stop the loop, I noticed it continues to make requests..
I want the loop to run every 5 or 10 seconds and when it navigates to another page to stop, also there has to be a timeout between each request (few seconds).

Here is my code:

```
function SearchForAMatch( {navigation, route}) {

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      let ew = ''
      fetch('https://SomeAPIWebsite/getrooms')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data =>  {
        ew = data.split("\n");
        for(let i = 0; i < ew.length - 1; i++)
        {
          if(ew[i].split('(')[0] == route.params?.region && ew[i].split('(')[2].split('/')[1] == route.params?.players && ew[i].split('(')[2].split('/')[0] != ew[i].split('(')[2].split('/')[1])
          { // new information! navigate to 'JoinRoom' screen
            navigation.navigate('JoinRoom', {row: i});
          }
        }
      })
    
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


  return (
    <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: hp('3%'), color: 'white', padding: 5, textAlign: 'center'}}>{route.params?.players}</Text>
    </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should use a timeout, and execute the api after timeout happen. Next timeout should start after a fetch completed. This will make sure it call the api after the last one completed.

Comment: I do have a timeout every 5 seconds, but its still continue to request when I navigate to another page

Comment: I mean to use setTimeOut. setInterval will create a new fetch request every 5th second no matter if the last one was resolved.

Comment: this might work, do I make the request and timeOut in the UseEffect()?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the previous screen is not unmounted when you navigate to the new screen so the clearInterval is never called. This happens when you're inside a StackNavigator for example. If this is the case then maybe you can make the fetch request inside the "focus" navigation event (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe just clear the interval when there's data after the navigate line.

```
          { // new information! navigate to 'JoinRoom' screen
            navigation.navigate('JoinRoom', {row: i});
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
```

Comment: It did solve the problem but created a new one, if I use clearInterval() I need to set it if the user repeats his action cuz right now it works the first time, but after that, it doesn't enter the useEffect function

Comment: i want to make sure I understand your second issue. So you want the fetch data to start again after the user goes back to the first page? (the page where it was fetching data every 5 seconds).

Comment: I figured it out haha, that was related to a different issue